# Trailblazer and Minitest - NameError: uninitialized constant MiniTest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, minitest, trailblazer

Environment:

```
rails -v
Rails 4.2.5

ruby -v
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

bundle list trailblazer
trailblazer-1.1.0
```

I am working through the examples in the Trailblazer book and I have run into a situation that I do not understand.  Following the set up given in the book, when I run a specific test using `bundle rake test/concerns/ar_invoice/crud_test.rb` it runs as expected.  However, if I simply run `bundle rake test` then I see this instead:

```
bundle rake test
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant MiniTest
./test/concepts/ar_invoice/crud_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
./bundle/lib/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in define'
./bundle  /lib/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `each'
./bundle/lib/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in define'
./bundle/lib/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `each'
./bundle/lib/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `block in define'
./bundle/lib/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:20:in `invoke_rake_task'
./bundle/lib/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:8:in `block in   <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => test:run
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The file crud_test.rb contains this:

```
cat test/concepts/ar_invoice/crud_test.rb

class ARInvoiceCrudTest < MiniTest::Spec
  describe( "Create" ) do
    it( "persists valid" ) do
      ar_invoice = ARInvoice::Create.(
        :ar_invoice => { :invoice_number => 101,
                         :client_number => 1234
        }
      ).model

      ar_invoice.persisted?.must_equal( true )
      ar_invoice.invoice_number.must_equal( 102 )
      ar_invoice.client_number.must_equal( 5678 )
    end
  end
end
```

And .test/test_helper.rb looks like this:

```
cat test/test_helper.rb

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

require 'rails/test_help'
require 'minitest/spec'
require "minitest/autorun"

require "trailblazer/rails/test/integration"
```

And `env | grep RAILS_ENV` produces no output.

What else am I missing in the set-up? Should not running `bundle rake test` simply pick up the crud_test.rb file and run the test identically to when the file is explicitly named on the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer:

**And of course, add `require 'test_helper'` on top of every test file!**